# Drupal 8 markdown filter

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I'd like to be able to enter markdown into a plain text field and output some text as bold. I.e. 'This **is bold** text'.

Using the ([Markdown input filter module](https://www.drupal.org/project/markdown)), I'm trying to set up the plain text input filter to swap out the markdown for html. The current [plain text filter is configured like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEhBm.png).

However, whatever configuration I try, it still just outputs the asterisks. Am I missing something or trying to achieve something that's not possible with the plain text input format?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add some code in question which shows what you have tried! So other developers could help.

Comment: To be honest, it's all standard D8 twig theming stuff. It's just the input filter through the UI I need to work.